# LilyPond: Figured bass help - Vertical figure order with bass figure extenders on

Tags: notation, lilypond, engraving, figured-bass

I'm having a bit of trouble obtaining the desired result in the following example:

```
\version "2.18.2"

<< 

  \relative c' {
    e2 e, 
  }

  \figuremode {
    \bassFigureExtendersOn
    < 4 >2 < 3+ >4 < 7 3+ > 
  }

>>
```

The result is [wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j25fC.jpg). The #3- should be under the 7, but it appears over it despite the order `< 7 3+ >` implying the 7 should be over.

I already tried by using a placeholder before or after the 4 `< _ 4 >` and `< 4 _ >` to no avail.

Does anyone know how to get the correct result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the "#3-" under the "7" you will need placeholder (underscore) `_` in the *connected* (second) figure, not the first figure:

`< 4 >2 < _ 3+ >4 < 7 3+ >`

[image: LilyPond output - figured bass fixed]